# Border Position

Tags: css

I want to try and achieve something in CSS using borders but they don't seem to have something I want. In Photoshop, when you add a Stroke (border), you select the position. Outside, Inside, or Center. Outside being where the entire border wraps around the object. Inside is where it sits on the inside (obviously), and center being half and half.

I want a `2px` border that's positioned in the center. So it shows 1px outside and `1px` inside. Is there anyway to do this with CSS? I imagine I can do it with a `box-shadow` of some kind but I'm horrendous at shadows in CSS.

There's also the issue of having to be pure CSS so I can't lay an image over it. Can someone possibly help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why it specifically have to be that way? Is that going to be adding some extra effect on some image or something like that?

Comment: @Spedwards it's not exactly clear what you mean by "inside" and "outside", example code would help.

Comment: @Michael_B Here's an example I just made in Photoshop. I want a "center" border just on a much smaller scale. http://imgur.com/a/NAVoC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a work around, since `border` represents outer stroke for you, you can make use of `outline` css property with `outline-offset` set to negative value to have the inner `1px` stroke<sup>( 1 )</sup> [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/2bx6jL9s/2/)

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#test {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px navy solid;  /* outer stroke */
  outline: 1px navy solid;  /* inner stroke */
  outline-offset: -2px;  /* negative border width + outline width */
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

<sup>( 1 )</sup> As the above fiddle might not demonstrate the explanation good enough, here's the same example with two colored strokes and `4px` for each stroke instead of `1px`  [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/2bx6jL9s/1/)

**Resources:**

http://caniuse.com/#search=outline

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_outline-offset.asp

https://davidwalsh.name/outline-offset

Comment: Problem is there is no such thing as `offline-left` so if you only want one side then this solution does not work. In my case I just nudged the container to fake it.
I'm getting carried away - but in CSS there is *always something*. Some limitation, side effect, etc. Do they do it on purpose?

Comment: @Rolf, sorry for replying too late, but I believe you can achieve it using `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements by giving the element `border-left` only

Comment: this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/otmauy71/ shows extra left border beside the inner and outer-strokes.. and this other fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/gtkdjh69/3/ shows only outer stroke with left border.. note that you can use this technique for any side border or even multi sides borders

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps with a suitable sized absolutely positioned pseudo-element?

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:-6px;
  left: -6px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);
  border:12px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could nudge the container so that it would look like it's an inner border. For example, if you have have a `2px` left border and want it to appear as an inner border, you can just offset the whole container to the right, like this:

```
position: relative;
left: 2px;
```

You might have to do other corrections, such as reducing the width of the container by `2px`.